# Calculate percentage of occurences of a value in a dataframe column based on another column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks something like below :

[image]

I need to calculate percentage of "contestants" (one of the value in Result column) that are still "operating" (one of the values in OperatingState column).

How can derive this in pandas ?

Update: Adding dtypes for columns

```
Startup           object
Product           object
Funding           object
Event             object
Result            object
OperatingState    object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `numpy` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
perc = (((df['Result'] == 'Contestant') & (df['OperatingState'] == 'Operating')).sum() / df.shape[0]) * 100
```

Tested on example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Result': ['Contestant', 's', 'Contestant', 's'], 'OperatingState': ['Operating', 'p', 'Operating', 'Operating']})

perc = (((df['Result'] == 'Contestant') & (df['OperatingState'] == 'Operating')).sum() / df.shape[0]) * 100
print(perc)
```

Output:

```
50.0
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]

Comment: @MithunSasidharan Edited my answer, does it work for you now ?

Comment: no I get the same error even now.

Comment: I tested the answer on a sample DataFrame, it works for me with no error. The error you're getting may be due to some other part of the code.

Comment: There might be a problem with the brackets, please try the code in my answer where I have enclosed the conditions individually within brackets.Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: it worked now with the updated answer of yours. Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it worked. :)